# Convert a string to html tags

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm fairly new to LWC development so please let me know if I'm heading the wrong way here.
I want to convert a string of html tags to html and to render it on my lightning component.

I followed the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385518/4276413) thread which suggests to create a new template and attach it, so I tried the following:

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Hmjr9kNoJ/2/edit)

HTML:

```html
<template>
    {text}
</template>
```

Javascript:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    get text(){
        var email = '<p>Dear Rosario,&nbsp;<br /> <br /> <br /> I saw your reply in the mail of case number&nbsp;2227. Please let&#39;s continue messaging here regarding the Delta PC issue and it&#39;s upcoming session, to make sure we are all aligned.&nbsp;<br /> <br /> As I wrote in the previous mail, our team will be ready on Monday, Oct 7, at 2 pm Jakarta time.<br /> &nbsp;</p';
        var template = document.createElement('template');
        email = email.trim(); 
        template.innerHTML = email;
        return template.content.firstChild;
    }
}
```

> output : [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly set `.innerHTML` property of HTMLElement unless you container element has been enabled `lwc:dom="manual"` directive. [HTML Template Directives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_directives)

```html
<template>
    <div class="email-text" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        this.template.querySelector('.email-text').innerHTML = 
        `<p>Dear Rosario,&nbsp;
             <br /> <br /> <br /> 
             I saw your reply in the mail of case number&nbsp;2227. Please let&#39;s continue messaging here regarding the Delta PC issue and it&#39;s upcoming session, to make sure we are all aligned.&nbsp;
             <br /> <br /> 
             As I wrote in the previous mail, our team will be ready on Monday, Oct 7, at 2 pm Jakarta time.
             <br /> &nbsp;
         </p>`;
    }
}
```